# How can I query select and change the value of the request in a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a problem changing a value in a Google sheet with this syntax:

```
=query(sheet!cell; "select column order by column " & if(sheet!column:column="value";"value1";"value2"))
```

If I try to only change the value, it works:

```
=query(sheet!column; "if column="value";"value1";"value2"")
```

If I try to take the value of the first sheet, it works:

```
=query(sheet!cell; "select column order by column")
```

How can I make a request QUERY SELECT and change the value of the request?

Comment: Probably syntax. Post your actual formula.

Comment: =query(Inscriptions!A2:O109; "select N order by A " & if(Inscriptions!N:N="oui";"R";"C") )

Answer (score 1):

You need a comma after the A and column R should be in your dataset if you want to use it to sort.  Try:

`=query(Inscriptions!A2:R109; "select N order by A, "&if(Inscriptions!N:N="oui";"R";"C"))`

Comment: Thanks Chris but it doesn't work. This make the request and result but the value changing doesn't work.